# Updating to most current version of customer information

Tags: sql-server-2016

I apologize in advance if there is a similar question out there already. I haven't had any luck finding anything. Basically, I run a small business and have four separate locations. With the current POS system we use, customer data is added/updated independently of each location. This means, for each customer, they have up to 4 customer IDs if they've visited all four locations. The information of course, will mostly constant for all four locations, but not in the following two cases: (1) The customer is new, (2) the customer updates their information at a particular location during their visit. I already figured how to handle new customers. However...

I'm trying write a query in SQL SERVER that automates the following for existing customers:

**1. Imports and appends each of the four .CSV files (customer lists) I export from my POS system.**
    
I've already accomplished this step with a simple BULK INSERT

**2. Compare this list to what is currently in the customer data and:**
    
a. For customers *WITH* four records in the newly imported list, I want to update all four records in the existing SQL table to the most current version of the customer's information. See example below:

**Month 1: DATA IN SQL TABLE**

```
Location |  Cust_ID  |  Name   |  Phone Number
----------------------------------------------
0000001  |  12345A   |  David  |  7025551234
0000002  |  12345B   |  David  |  7025551234
0000003  |  12345C   |  David  |  7025551234
0000004  |  12345D   |  David  |  7025551234
```

**Month 2: DATA TO COMPARE TO SQL TABLE**

```
Location |  Cust_ID |  Name   |  Phone Number
---------------------------------------------
0000001  |  12345A  |  David  |   7025551234
0000002  |  12345B  |  David  |   7025559999
0000003  |  12345C  |  David  |   7025551234
0000004  |  12345D  |  David  |   7025551234
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
Location |  Cust_ID |  Name   |   Phone Number
----------------------------------------------
0000001  |  12345A  |  David  |   7025559999
0000002  |  12345B  |  David  |   7025559999
0000003  |  12345C  |  David  |   7025559999
0000004  |  12345D  |  David  |   7025559999
```

You guys might be thinking, "this guy just needs a new POS software provider." You're probably right, and I will once my wife is on-board with the idea of big change. In the meantime, this is what I'm stuck with. Thank you guys in advance for your help.

Comment: Do all 4 locations share the same database? Does every `Cust_ID` end in A,B,C, or D? Is there a `Date Modified` column, so we can easily tell that newest phone number?

Comment: Great questions! At this time, The database I maintain includes all four locations in one table, but the databases from which I export new/updated info on customers are separate. This is why I mentioned that I append all four together before comparing to the combined database I'm trying to maintain. The customer ID's are actually numeric only. They can be anything, but the entires for other fields in any given month should be identical across all four customer ID's. Lastly, I AM maintaining a  date modified column.

Comment: If your customer David, visits all 4 locations he will have 4 completely different `Cust_ID`'s? If so, how do you determine which Davids to group together?